# Excel and Word behaving difrerently in the same code

Tags: vbscript, ms-office, typename

I have a problem - instances of Excel and Word behave differently in the same procedure. Have a look at the code. The idea there is to have a procedure that handles resaving files in excel and word in various format combinations.

The problem is that I notice that word and excel behave differently - the appWord and appExcel have different type names. At some point appWord is changed from Application to Object, which then makes it impossible to close it. I don't understand the differences in the behaviour, since the code applied to them is identical.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso
Dim appWord
Dim appExcel
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

startWord
ResaveFiles appWord.Documents, "docx", 12, 0
appWord.quit

startExcel
ResaveFiles appExcel.Workbooks, "xlsx", 51, 56
appExcel.quit


MsgBox "All done."


Sub ResaveFiles(appType, srcExtName, srcExtNum, tmpExtNum)
Dim objFile
Dim objOpenFile
Dim strDirectory
    For Each objFile in fso.GetFolder(".").Files
        If lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = srcExtName Then
                If typeName(appType) = "Documents" Then StartWord
                If typeName(appType) = "Workbooks" Then StartExcel  
            Set objOpenFile = appType.Open(objFile.path)
            strDirectory = fso.BuildPath(objOpenFile.path, fso.GetBaseName(objOpenFile.name) & "._temp")
            objOpenFile.SaveAs strDirectory, tmpExtNum
            objOpenFile.Close
            msgBox typename(appType) & objFile
            msgBox typename(appWord) 'First typename test
            msgBox Typename(appExcel)
                If typeName(appType) = "Documents" Then appWord.Quit
                If typeName(appType) = "Workbooks" Then appExcel.Quit   
            set objOpenFile = appType.Open(strDirectory)
            objOpenFile.SaveAs objFile.path, srcExtNum
            objOpenFile.Close
            fso.DeleteFile(strDirectory)
            msgBox typename(appWord) 'Second typename test
    msgBox Typename(appExcel)
        End If  
    Next
    End Sub

'Start Word
 Sub StartWord
            Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                appWord.visible = false
                appWord.DisplayAlerts = false
    End Sub

'Start Excel
Sub StartExcel
            Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                appExcel.visible = false
                appExcel.DisplayAlerts = false
End Sub
```

I have tested it in the following way (with two typename tests) - when there are word files available, first appWord is Application and appExcel is empty, then it changes to Object and appExcel stays Empty (in this case we get an error when the subprocedure ends at AppWord.Quit). When there are no word files, and the script is processing Excels, first appWord is Object and appExcel is Application, then appWord is still Object and appExcel is still Application - in this case there are no errors when the subprocedure ends, on the appExcel.Quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm wrong, just my opinion:

```
If typeName(appType) = "Documents" Then appWord.Quit
If typeName(appType) = "Workbooks" Then appExcel.Quit   

set objOpenFile = appType.Open(strDirectory)
```

`appType` is a reference to what `appWord.Documents` or `appExcel.Workbooks` are referencing before entering your ResaveFiles Sub, where you instantiate a new copy of 'Excel.Application' or 'Word.Application', and in each of the cases, you instruct the application TO QUIT. The question is not why in the case of word you got an error. From my point of view YOU SHOULD got an error. The question is why, if instructed to quit, excel keeps open and maintaining references to handle your code.

EDIT - And not tried. Just adapted from OP code. Adapt as needed

```
Option Explicit

    ResaveFiles "Word.Application", "docx", 12, 0
    ResaveFiles "Excel.Application", "xlsx", 51, 56

MsgBox "All done."


Sub ResaveFiles(progID, srcExtName, srcExtNum, tmpExtNum )
Dim app, doc
Dim fso, objFile, objOpenFile, strDirectory

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each objFile in fso.GetFolder( "." ).Files
        If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName( objFile.Name )) = srcExtName Then

            ' Get references
            Set app = GetNewAppInstance( progID )
            Set doc = GetDocumentHandler( app )

            ' Save temp
            Set objOpenFile = doc.Open( objFile.Path )
            strDirectory = fso.BuildPath( objOpenFile.path, fso.GetBaseName(objOpenFile.name) & "._temp" )
            objOpenFile.SaveAs strDirectory, tmpExtNum
            objOpenFile.Close

            ' Release objects
            Set objOpenFile = nothing 
            Set doc = nothing 
            app.Quit
            Set app = nothing

            ' Get references again
            Set app = GetNewAppInstance( progID )
            Set doc = GetDocumentHandler( app )

            ' Resave file
            Set objOpenFile = doc.Open( strDirectory )
            objOpenFile.SaveAs objFile.path, srcExtNum
            objOpenFile.Close

            ' Release objects
            Set objOpenFile = nothing 
            Set doc = nothing 
            app.Quit
            Set app = nothing

            ' Clean
            fso.DeleteFile(strDirectory)

        End If
    Next 

End Sub


Function GetNewAppInstance( ByVal progID )
    Set GetNewAppInstance = CreateObject( progID )
    With GetNewAppInstance
        .Visible = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
End Function

Function GetDocumentHandler( app )
    Dim name
    name = app.Name
    If InStr(name,"Excel") > 0 Then
        Set GetDocumentHandler = app.Workbooks
    ElseIf InStr(name,"Word") > 0 Then
        Set GetDocumentHandler = app.Documents
    Else
        Set GetDocumentHandler = app
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: To give a little background - what the code needs to do is to open a file, save it in a different format, close the program, reopen the program, open the newly temp created file and save it back in the original format (and delete the newly created temporary file) - and that's it. 

I know that I could have it done (more) easily in two separate procedures for Word and Excel, but as a challange I wanted to make it a bit more generic. My problem is why is appWord an Object instead of an Application, contrary to appExcel?

Comment: Your problem is you are saying to the application it must quit. You lose reference to word application because you are closing it. Why? What you should do is close the open document, not quit the application.

Comment: The need to close application arises from something different (long story), and it is absolutely necessary that Office is closed and reopened. I should be able to open word again without problems, especially that it does work for excel just fine...

Comment: Then, instead of passing a reference to a object obtained from a application instance that you will later quit, pass to the sub the class of the object, and, instantiate, quit and reinstantiate everything inside ResaveFiles. And don't keep references to object obtained from a closed application.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's a bit more advanced scripting than I am currently capable of:) Since I am a beginner, I don't know much about classes - I'll learn up and see what I can do - thanks again.

Comment: Not more advanced, just more organized. Updated answer to show the general idea.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot for a sample of code! so, you are not actually defining classes for Word and Excel, but using functions to create the objects!

Comment: Since all the code is the same except for the `Workbooks/Documents` properties, moved it out of the main logic.

Comment: OK, basically your code seems to work, which is awesome. (The only thing that I have changed is `InStr(name,"Excel") >= 0` to `InStr(name,"Excel") >= 1`. Thanks a lot - I will have to digest the code and find the reason why did my code fail in the first place. And also, just for "fun", I'll try to create a class for OfficeApp, to see how it may work!